# Laravel - Storage::url() não retorna url correta

Tags: php, laravel

Iniciei no laravel a pouco tempo, no momento os arquivos estão sendo armazenados dentro da pasta storage, mas irei usar a biblioteca de armazenamento na nuvem do google cloud, consigo criar e ler arquivos normalmente mas o problema é ao tentar obter a url do arquivo para poder vizualizar os arquivos no aplicativo que vai estar consumindo minha api rest.

Essa é a estrutura de arquivos:

```
storage
      |- app
      |    |- data
      |    |- public 
      |            |- images
      |                    |- produtos
      |                    |- supermercados
                                          |- 1
                                             | - 9d92b1d506a2065c4c0d132dbeb32217016d2a57f67a48ca7373cdff6bcd9ee6.jpeg
df974bf001ec886ab8ace6cdfab5850cf12ae66323927d55ccf591cc2f3079c0.jpeg
      |- framework
      |- logs
```

Estou tentando obter o link assim:

```
Storage::url('data/images/supermercados/' . $supermercado->id . '/' . $supermercado->foto);
```

Onde id é a pasta do supermercado e foto é o nome da foto

Porém ao invés de receber um link eu recebo este caminho:

```
 \/storage\/data\/images\/supermercados\/1\/df974bf001ec886ab8ace6cdfab5850cf12ae66323927d55ccf591cc2f3079c0.jpeg
```

Como faço para obter uma URL como http://site.com/imagem.jpge ?

Comment: Basta setar uma rota com esse nome `/imagem.jpge` e na rota escrita no controller coloque algo como `public function imagem() { return Storage::download('data/images/supermercados/' . $supermercado->id . '/' . $supermercado->foto, 'image.jpg', [ 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg' ]); }`

Comment: Tive um problema parecido com esse ontem. Faça um teste. Abra o `php artisan tinker` e digite `env('APP_URL')`. Se tiver retornando diferente do que está no arquivo `.env`, é bem provável que sua pasta `bootstrap/cache` tenha salvo alguma informação vazia ou diferente da configuração atual. Se não me engano, pode ser resolvido facilmente com `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou em dúvida, eu uso uma biblioteca para carregar as imagens chamada Glide, ao passar a url ela vai efetuar um download ou a biblioteca vai carregar ela do servidor?

Comment: Vc disse q estava usando um cloud, então isso seria interno da propria API do laravel para resolver, agora se vc fez algo proprio não temos como saber e a duvida fica ambígua. Se puder detalhar nos ajudará a ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema parecido com esse ontem.

Eu estava tendo a url completa na minha máquina local e de mais duas pessoas funcionando corretamente, mostrando o caminho completo, ao chamar `Storage::url`. Porém, quando estava em produção, o caminho era retornado apenas com uma `/` antes.

O que acontece é que o Laravel geralmente utiliza o que está em `APP_URL` para poder montar a URL, em casos da configuração do disco `public`, no arquivo `config/filesystems.php`. E as demais configurações de storage também têm suas próprias configurações.

O que aconteceu foi que o Laravel criou um cache dentro da pasta `bootstrap/cache`, com valores que estavam bem diferente do `.env` ou dentro da pasta `config`.

O problema pode ser resolvido removendo ou renovando o `cache` de configuração, para forçar a atualização desses valores.

Você pode rodar o comando `php artisan config:clear` ou `php artisan config:cache` para tentar resolver isso.

Um bom teste é fazer o seguinte:

1 - Abra o `.env`e altere o valor de `APP_URL` para um valor qualquer, só pra testar.
2 - Abra o `php artisan tinker` e digite `env('APP_URL')`. Em seguida, dê ENTER pra exibir o valor.
2 - Compare o valor que está em `.env` e o valor retornado no seu terminal.

Se os valores forem diferentes, tente verificar se a pasta `bootstrap/cache` possui o arquivo `config.php` (que é o arquivo de cache de configuração).

Caso tenha problemas de permissão, você não consiga remover com o comando `php artisan config:clear`. Você pode optar por apagar o arquivo `config.php` manualmente.

**NOTA**: O problema do cache de configuração me causou problemas tanto na montagem de URL no disk `public` quanto no `cloud` que uso. Ambos os casos estava exibindo informações diferente do que estava configurado ou esperado.

Comment: Fiz o que você disse o APP_URL esta retornando localhost, porém no Storage::url() retorna nada

Comment: No caso, você conferiu o arquivo `filesystems.php`? Geralmente, onde está configurado como `disks.public`, tem um trecho que contém a montagem da url, dessa forma `'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage`.

Comment: Outra coisa: Chama `echo Storage::url('')` em uma rota qualquer e chama `Storage::url('')` no `php artisan tinker`. Veja se os resultados são idênticos. Eu estava tendo problemas quando chamava via Browser e Via Terminal. Os resultados eram diferentes.

Comment: @SamuelIves rode o comando `ls bootstrap/config` e vê se aparece algo. Claro, se tiver usando algum sistema Unix Like. No Windão, só entra na pasta e vê se têm algo lá

Comment: 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: Se root aponta para public então por que Storage::put() coloca em data?

Comment: Porque `root` é a raiz. O caminho que você passa como argumento de `put`, é acrescentado o que está defindo em `root`. Exemplo: `Storage::put('pasta/arquivo.txt', 'meu arquivo')` irá criar o caminho `storage/app/public/pasta/arquivo.txt`.

Comment: Storage::put('data/juno/token.json', json_encode($tokenData)); ele deveria estar indo para public

Comment: O Laravel separa esses arquivos na pasta `public`, porque, quando é invocado `php artisan storage:link`, é criado um link simbólico (atalho) dentro da pasta public, para disponibilizar a visualização dos arquivos através da `$url/storage/$caminho_do_arquivo`.

Comment: Sobre a pasta que você está armazenando, é melhor sempre você conferir qual é o adapter configurado em `filesystems.default`. Você pode olhar o arquivo `config/filesystems.php` ou mesmo chamar no `php artisan tinker`: `config('filesystems.default')`

Comment: Esta tudo configurado como local, php artisan storage:link cria a pasta public porém apenas com um .gitignore

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema porém, sempre que eu enviar um arquivo vou ter que abrir o terminal e digitar: php artisan storage:link? E por que o laravel duplica os arquivos criando uma pasta storage no diretório public?

Comment: Ele não duplica. Como eu disse antes, isso é um link simbólico (é como se fosse um atalho do windows)

Comment: Sim, é que no vs code não mostra como atalho, mas ao verificar no explorador de arquivos vi que é um link mesmo, problema resolvido, bastou acessar com asset()

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com problema semelhante. Funcionando perfeitamente no localhost, com VS Code etc. Fiz o DEPLOY acertei vários probleminhas, mas as imagens não apareciam na relação dos itens (Biblioteca ==> capa dos livros, logo das editoras, fotos dos usuários e dos leitores) e nem nas visualizações. Apliquei php artisan route:cache; php artisan route:clear; php artisan cache:clear; php artisan view:clear; php artisan config:cache; php artisan config:clear e, depois composer dump-autoload, seguido de php artisan storage:link. Funcionou.